# Modifying VBA code to place n entries below an entry rather than just the entry itself

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following VBA code:

```
Sub test()
    Dim w1 As Worksheet
    Dim w2 As Worksheet

    Dim k As Long

    Dim c As Range
    Dim d As Range
    Dim strFA As String

    Set w1 = Sheets("a")
    Set w2 = Sheets("b")

    w2.Cells.Clear
    k = 1

    With w1.Range("A:A")
        Set c = .Cells.Find("Name:" After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), lookat:=xlWhole)
        strFA = ""
        While Not c Is Nothing And strFA <> c.Address
            If strFA = "" Then strFA = c.Address
            If IsError(Application.Match(c.Offset(1, 0).value, w2.Range("A:A"), False)) Then
                Set d = .Cells.Find("Birthday:", c, , xlWhole)
                w2.Range("A" & k).value = c.Offset(0, 1).value
                w2.Range("B" & k).value = d.Offset(1, 0).value
                k = k + 1
            End If
            Set c = .Cells.Find("Name:", After:=c, lookat:=xlWhole)
        Wend
    End With

End Sub
```

The short version of what this code does is as follows:

1) Set the first sheet that should be searched and the second sheet (output sheet) that the results should be appended to.

2) Search the first column for a certain string "NAME:" and once found take the value in the second column, place it in the output sheet go look for "Birthday:" Once "Birthday:" is found put the value below it beside "NAME:" in the output sheet.

3) Repeat until there are no more entries.

I'm wondering how I might extend this code so that rather than searching for the value below "Birthday:" we instead search for n entries below birthday and place each one beside the value for "NAME:" in succession so that the result looks like:

```
Col1   Col2   Col3 Col4
James   10     15  1974
```

Where the input looks similar to:

```
Col1   Col2   Col3 Col4
Name:  James
Something
Birthday: 
10
15
1974
```

Please let me know if anything is unclear.  You can assume that the three values after Birthday: always appear directly after and that James is always in the column directly beside Name: but no assumptions can be made about how far apart Name: is from Birthday:, how many blank spaces are present, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a loop that has an incremented index. for each row you go down you write to one column to the right.  Something like this.

```
    lRow = 4
    lCol = 2
    'Loop through reading the birthday.
    Do While lRow <= n

        'Here we are writing a column to the right each time we come through.
        ws.Range(lCol & k)

        lCol  = lCol + 1
        lRow = lRow + 1
        ws.Range("A" & lRow).Activate
    Loop
```

So after you have the name and you are ready to read the birthday cells.  Read them like that and write them to the cells on the current row.

Comment: Thanks, do you have any suggestions on how to integrate that into the current code?  It isn't my own so unfortunately I'm not entirely certain on setup.

Comment: @114 Without being able to see what all the code is doing and debug it, I'm not sure if I can integrate it.  If you can debug it, find the spot when you have gotten the name, then read the birthday like this and write the output as the birthday is being read.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look and try to implement it!